# Como colocar um scrollView dentro um TextView se já tenho um scrollView no layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu coloquei um scrollView no layout e ainda precisava colocar um scrollview no TextView, porém só um deles funciona, se já tenho no layout, no textView não funciona. Alguém sabe um jeito de deixar os dois? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Nunca cheguei a usar, mas a `support library v4` tem o [`NestedScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html), que deve ser interessante nesse caso.

Comment: Tem uma resposta que pode te ajudar aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: Eu já tinha visto está resposta. Acontece o mesmo problema, ou funciona o scroll do TextView ou funciona o do layout?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, vc conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Alguém sabe a solução desse problema?

Comment: @daniel12345smith Ter uma `ScrollView` dentro de uma outra não é uma boa prática. Você pode melhorar seu código mostrando apenas uma parte do texto e inserindo um 'AlertDialog' para mostrar seu texto total;.

Answer (score 1):

**usando NestedScrollView**
Existem algumas soluções que você poderia adicionar, a fim de chegar a este trabalho, mas não há necessidade para isso. Biblioteca de suporte Android v4 tem uma classe chamada NestedScrollView e ele faz exatamente o que o nome sugere.

Exemplo:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nested_scroll_view_height">

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/cards_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Na maioria das vezes você provavelmente não precisa de duas scrollviews na mesma tela, mas se você precisar dele NestedScrollView é uma grande solução. Essa classe tem um conjunto de métodos úteis para que você possa desativar a rolagem aninhada, verificar se a sua exibição de rolagem aninhada tem aninhados rolagem pai e assim por diante.

pode verificar a documentação oficial para mais informações.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html